# Converted string to json, how to get the label and data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

the value of props.record.DataUpdate.draft

```
{"FirstName": "This is my firstname","MiddleName": "This is my middlename","LastName": "this is my lastname"}
```

let newData = JSON.parse(props.record.DataUpdate.draft)

console.log(newData)

```
{
  "FirstName": "This is my firstname",
  "MiddleName": "This is my middlename",
  "LastName": "this is my lastname"
}
```

this is my database looks like

```
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  tableNameToBeUpdated: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  tableIdToBeUpdated: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  draft: {
    type: Sequelize.JSON,
  },
  CreatedDate: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
  },
  LastUpdateDate: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
  },
  status: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
```

what I want here is to get the label (Fistname,Lastname,Middlename) with there perspective value,

*note* the label can be change it depends on the string that saves on draft column

how to achieve that?

Comment: Not clear, you have the label with their respective values with JSON.parse().

What's the link between your question and your DB ?

Maybe you're looking for Object.keys() ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
const jsonString = {"FirstName": "This is my firstname","MiddleName": "This is my middlename","LastName": "this is my lastname"}


for (var key in jsonString) {
       console.log(key + " -> " + jsonString[key]);
}
```

This gives me the Output:

```
'FirstName -> This is my firstname'
'MiddleName -> This is my middlename'
'LastName -> this is my lastname'
```

Edit:
Ok i took the example form your post (without the single quotes). Then just do what you posted and then use the for loop:

```
const jsonString = '{"FirstName": "This is my firstname","MiddleName": "This is my middlename","LastName": "this is my lastname"}'

const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString)

for (var key in jsonObject) {
  console.log(key + " -> " + jsonObject[key]);
}
```

Comment: the result is not the same on my end, the result is `0 -> {`

Comment: `1 -> "` , `2 -> F` and so on

Comment: it because my `{"FirstName": "This is my firstname","MiddleName": "This is my middlename","LastName": "this is my lastname"}` is `'{"FirstName": "This is my firstname","MiddleName": "This is my middlename","LastName": "this is my lastname"}'`

Comment: I have  ` ' ' `,

Comment: Have a look at my edit